C# Naming Convention for private properties with backing field
Is there an official naming convention for private properties?
I use them for lazy initialization of expensive fields:
private string _veryExpensive;
private string VeryExpensive => _veryExpensive ??= VeryExpensiveInit();

I feel like since it's private it should be named _veryExpensive, but then it clashes with the backer field name and one of them has to be renamed.
Is it recommended to use PascalCase VeryExpensive
or maybe _VeryExpensive for the private property name?
With property-scoped fields I wouldn't have to define another private backing field, but it's not implemented yet: open proposal
I'm not specifically asking for a lazy init, there's other use cases of private properties with a backing field: Are there any reasons to use private properties in C#?

Why not use Lazy: private Lazy<string> _veryExpensive = new Lazy<string>(VeryExpensiveInit);

@KlausGütter Because I don't want to access it with the .Value property of Lazy. So even when using Lazy, I would do private VeryExpensive => _veryExpensive.Value;

I amnot sure what you are asking - are you getting any error with code you presented? Because i do not.

@Michał Turczyn I'm asking if there's a naming convention for private properties. If it's PascalCase or should be _camelCase, but then how to rename either the property or the field since they will have the same name

No, there is no naming convention here. Or rather: there are any number of naming conventions enforced to a greater or lesser degree by individual teams.

@KlausGütter I would absolutely use the OP's version, not Lazy<T> here. You're introducing a lot of overhead, complexity and allocations there to do something really simple.

I agree, what you have right now is the closest to "official recommendations". And, by common sense, you have no other choice :) You can also observe such usage in linked question.

@MarcGravell Unless multiple threads could be accessing VeryExpensive simultaneously - then you have to use some form of thread safety (and Lazy<T> would probably be the best solution for that scenario).

@MatthewWatson it might be a solution; "the best" is questionable and depends on the requirements and measures used (personally my eyes are immediately drawn to the extra allocations - delegate, lazy, etc), but that would only be relevant if this is a high volume type - totally fair to ignore that for low volume), but yes: it will absolutely work

@MatthewWatson Thanks for the hint. But you don't have to use thread safety, if init is allowed to run multiple times. I'd rather have multiple possible init executions on the first accesses, but less data allocated and faster access times since performance is of importance here

@MarcGravell I just realzied you are THE Marc Gravell :O It's an honor to have you here! Been using your FastMember for a long time until I just now replaced it with source generators for even more speed. Thanks for your open source!

You have the correct naming convention already.
What you are using is effectively a Expression bodied property. In C#, property names should use Pascal Case.
There is no difference in the naming conventions for public and private properties, so you are already using the correct convention.
